# What does "Avon" mean? Avon Lady

Tags: meaning

In his book *Perfect English Grammar*, Grant Barrett, writes in the preface: *"I grew up in Missouri. My father was a cop. My mother was an **Avon** lady.*" I know the adjective *A1* that describes the finest quality of a product or even a person. However, I read the word *Avon*, and confused about its meaning. It is not found in the [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Avon).

Question: What is the history and mystery behind this strange word? Has anyone heard or read this before? Is it even a real word?

Comment: It's in [Macmillan](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/avon-lady#:~:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary,by%20calling%20at%20people's%20houses) (and UD, and Wikipedia). Not to be confused with the Michelin Man.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that has to be the best dictionary. I bookmarked it. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't say that at all. I just searched for "Avon lady" + meaning on Google. 'Michelin Man' refers to a company mascot/icon, and so the term properly belongs in a reference work outside a standard dictionary, like 'Michelin', 'London' and 'Elvis'. 'Avon lady' is really a proprietary term also, which is why the dictionaries probably omit it.

Comment: An Avon lady sold Avon products door to door. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to a specific company called "*Avon*"

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avon_Products)

> Avon uses both door-to-door salespeople ("Avon ladies", as well as "Avon men") and brochures to advertise its products.

The word itself is from Welsh or Common Brittonic and means "river". Indeed there are several rivers called Avon.

Comment: thanks so much. So this word is used as a complement, rather than adjective? Like "cleaning lady". ?

Comment: It's her actual job. She went door-to-door selling/advertising make-up. It has no connotation.

Comment: @Michael16: As *Avon* is the name of a product line, it's a noun. It's an attributive noun that acts like an adjective to modify *lady*. Like *chicken* in *chicken soup*.

Comment: @Michael16 Yes, a noun-complement. An 'Avon lady' is a lady selling products from the company of Avon. The company sold cosmetic products. Being an Avon lady was as a company representative who got orders and made deliveries 'in the field' without a physical store by visiting other women who wanted these cosmetics. The phrase ['Avon lady calling'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vgqh6fcbiW0) was popularized in commercials in the mid 20th c. There is no connection whatsoever with 'A1'.

Comment: @dubious Feel free to add these details from any of the comments to your answer to improve it for the OP.

Comment: It has a certain connotation of a suburban woman, particularly in parts of America away from the big cities, capitalist endeavour, traditional gender roles where women look pretty and wear dresses and men work, nothing improper. [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2011/aug/18/125-years-avon-calling) refers to "the 'Avon lady' stereotype of some suburban Stepford wife in a pillbox hat, tottering door-to-door to flog lipsticks like double glazing"; although it says this is dated, it seems to match the quote above with the father a cop (traditionally a very masculine job).

Comment: A condescending, smug opinion by our friends at the Guardian, but yes, there are those who feel that way. My mother, an Avon lady for years in one of the US's urban centers, would be surprised by the  characterization, especially the "tottering" part. But thanks, it certainly made me chuckle!